# Need help locating a paper

Tags: reference-request, math-history, philosophy

One of the references of the paper

Paulo Régis C. Ruffino, A Criticism on "A Mathematician's Apology" by G. H. Hardy (arXiv:1112.4499 [math.HO])

is:

Vershik, A. M. – A Dangerous Joke, The Mathematical Intelligencer, Vol.20 no 2 1989

But neither the (online) contents page of the Intelligencer, nor Vershik's homepage seems to know
this latter paper, and even Google doesn't seem to know about it.
(BTW, Vol 20 of the Intelligencer dates from 1998, not 1989, but I checked both places.)

Does anyone know this paper?

Comment: Why don't you write directly to Paulo and ask him? Here's his address: Departamento de Matem´atica, Universidade Estadual de Campinas,
13.081-970 - Campinas - SP, Brazil. e-mail: ruﬃno@ime.unicamp.br

Comment: [A Criticism on "A Mathematician's Apology"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4499v1.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in

- The Mathematical Intelligencer, Spring 1998, Volume 20, Issue 2, page 40

It is available for download in the link http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03025296

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you!!